# More traditional / professional word or phrase for 'Plan of Attack'

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm currently writing up a design document which is essentially a 'plan of attack', however this doesn't strike me as a particularly professional or eloquent term for what I mean and my mind's gone blank as to the alternatives.

'Plan of action'? ...Still sounds too casual.

Answer (score 4):

*Strategy* often goes down well these days.

Comment: true but strategy for what? The document is specifically about what steps to take and when. 'Strategy going forwards' I guess?

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer to me

Comment: @SirYakalot I could ask the same of "Plan of attack". Plan of attack for what?

Comment: @SirYakalot: " strategy for what?" this depends purely on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SirYakalot you can't have a strategy going backwards.

Comment: Yes well that's why I asked the question - because plan of attack is inappropriate. Going forwards just means 'a strategy for how we're going to progress through the work' as opposed to a strategy for anything else.

Comment: Then what of *design* strategy?

Comment: We do not ask "for what?" of the word *strategy*! The word strategy is word with military connotations which means pretty much exactly the same thing as *plan of attack*, also a term with military connotations. The answer to "strategy for what" is, "strategy for the attack, doh?"

Answer (score 3):

The most popular peaceful word used in this context is `roadmap`, a document that presents the detailed timeline of given process.

A `checklist` may not be so official-looking but nevertheless a popular.

`Battle plan` may be taken a bit humorously if it's not really a battle.

`strategy` isn't bad, but may be a little too generic (encompassing solution to a family of similar problems)

`

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a plain old *plan* is perfectly good, but a *course*, a *course of action*, or a *process* might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the plan of attack in a military context? If so, the term battle plan would probably be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase to consider using from a retired (combat veteran) Marine.
**OPERATION PLAN OR ORDER:** A combat plan or
order dealing with tactical operations and setting
forth the mission of the unit; it deals with the
commander’s decision, plan of action, and such
details as to the method of execution as will ensure
coordinated action by the whole command.